# Creating a custom tab view, with each tab containing a scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

Im trying to create an inventory page in an ios game. My design is to lock the view to landscape, then use half the screen for the "bag" or inventory (this is the tabs). The other half would be a display for details + menu controls

By selecting each tab, the corresponding view should be brought to the front of the view. Each view contains a scroll view and a static  background image. The image is slightly bigger than the scroll layer since the image carries a border.

Since i only want a partial part of the view to be a tab view, i cant really take advantage of uitabbarcontroller.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell me more about a tab view..

Comment: What i meant by a tab view is there are mutliple views layered ontop of each other. By selecting the correspondin tab, it would bring that view ontop

Comment: Make your own navbar with as many icons as you need, and on click do a transition.